# Adobe Air - FileMode.APPEND

Tags: xml, air

I'm using the code below to add an image id to a .XML file:

```
var xmlGallery:XML =new XML ('<ENTRY "IMG_ID="' +img_id+'"/>')

var fGallery:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("gallery.xml");
var sGallery:FileStream = new FileStream();

sGallery.open(fGallery,FileMode.APPEND);
sGallery.writeUTFBytes(xmlGallery.toXMLString());
```

The .XML output looks like this:

```
<ENTRY "IMG_ID="1"/> 
<ENTRY "IMG_ID="2"/>
<ENTRY "IMG_ID="3"/>
```

I need to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` above the entries. 
How to do it?

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply write the string before appending any XML nodes to the file? Try:

```
sGallery.open(fGallery, FileMode.APPEND);
sGallery.writeUTF("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
sGallery.writeUTFBytes(xmlGallery.toXMLString());
```

Update: Changes in problem statement based on OP's comments:

It is difficult to say without looking at the source code. What I can understand is you are updating the same XML file multiple times. In that case, your best bet is to do the following:

- Check if the file exists or not,

  - If it doesn't create one and add the XML declaration and the `GALLERY` opening and closing tags (i.e. the `GALLERY` element)
  - If it does exist do nothing
- Read in the file in an object of type `XML`
- Add all child elements to this object using E4X (the recommended way of XML handling in AS3)
- When you're done adding/modifying the XML object save it back to the file

You should also take a look at the `asx3m` XML serialization library [here](http://code.google.com/p/asx3m/).

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. This is the result (Every entry get the encoding added): `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><ENTRY "IMG_ID="1"/> 
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><ENTRY "IMG_ID="2"/>
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><ENTRY "IMG_ID="3"/>`

Comment: @Uli: Aha! I guess you are opening the file multiple times and appending entries to it? If that is the case, open the file once before you start processing your image data (or whatever), write the XML document declaration, close it and then keep appending.

Comment: OK I did it like this: `sGallery.openAsync(fGallery,flash.filesystem.FileMode.UPDATE);
sGallery.writeUTFBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"); 

sGallery.openAsync(fGallery,flash.filesystem.FileMode.APPEND);
sGallery.writeUTFBytes(xmlGallery.toXMLString());` Maybe it helps somebody. I used **UPDATE** instead of **WRITE**.

Comment: Just run into another problem with it. How to add a closing element (In my case: </GALLERY>) to the XML to make it valid? E.g: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><GALLERY><ENTRY "IMG_ID="1"/> 
<ENTRY "IMG_ID="2"/>
<ENTRY "IMG_ID="3"/>
</GALLERY>`  Any ideas welcome!

Comment: @Uli: Once you're done appending all the `ENTRY` objects, open the file once more, append the `</GALLERY>` string and close it.

Comment: OK, but how does this work if after the first session the </GALLERY> element is in the XML? For the first session it's working but in a second and third the XML shows up with multiple </GALLERY> closing elements.